# Java nested data structure to JSON/XML

Tags: java, json, xml, maps

I have a key-value structure that needs to be converted to JSON and XML using Java.
The problem with this data is that the structure is not the same so I can't use model objects. I believe my best shot is to convert first into a Map of Objects, where the Objects can be a Map or an Array.

Example

```
order.name=John Doe
order.address=London
order.items[0].name="Milk"
order.items[0].price="1.23"
order.items[0].unit="2"
order.items[1].name="Bread"
order.items[1].price="4.56"
order.items[1].unit="1"
```

The JSON would be:

```
{
    "order": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "address": "London",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Milk",
                "price": "1.23",
                "unit": "2"
            },{
                "name": "Bread",
                "price": "4.56",
                "unit": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and the XML:

```
<order>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <address>London</address>
    <items>
        <item>
            <name>Milk</name>
            <price>1.23</price>
            <unit>2</unit>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>Bread</name>
            <price>4.56</price>
            <unit>1</unit>
        </item>     
    </items>
</order>
```

Is there any library that would facilitate the conversion of the key-value into a map of object structure?

Comment: Have a look at Jackson

Comment: Underscore-java can convert json to xml.

Comment: I need first to create the map from the key-value keystore. I saw Jackson has methods to get a value from a path, but couldn't find anything to add a value to path.